# Why such a big discrepancy in unique events between Google Analytics and BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the number of unique events in BigQuery and despite my efforts, the results are not even close to what I see in GA. Certain rows have up to 50% difference between BQ and GA, and I can't figure out why. Total events and users are exactly the same as in GA, it's only unique events that don't match.

I am using a CONCAT function to build the sessionID, and when used to calculate total sessions for a given period, it returns a very close number to what I see in GA. But as soon as I use it with the event category column, the numbers are off.

This is my query:

```
SELECT h.eventInfo.eventCategory, 
count(h.eventInfo.eventCategory) as total_events, 
count(distinct CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING))) as unique_events 
FROM `marketing-stack.12345678.ga_sessions_20190525` as ga,
UNNEST(ga.hits) as h 
GROUP BY h.eventInfo.eventCategory
```

For example, the top event looks like this in GA:

- 4276 total events - 3155 unique events - 1510 users

And in BigQuery:

- 4276 total events - 1566 unique events - 1510 users

Am I doing something wrong in the query or is there a difference between GA and BQ in regards to unique events and how you count them that I don't grasp?

I'd appreciate any help or input because I'm at loss here!

Comment: [I made a decent answer to this discrepency/delta in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203413/counting-google-analytics-unique-events-in-bigquery/66974347#66974347)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting users with events and not unique events ...

Action and label mustn't be `NULL` when you `COUNT(DISTINCT )` them.

```
SUM( (SELECT
 COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
    coalesce(h.eventinfo.eventaction,  ''),
    coalesce(h.eventinfo.eventlabel, '')
 )) FROM t.hits h ) ) uniqueEvents
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203413/counting-google-analytics-unique-events-in-bigquery/49305147#49305147)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had read the other thread with your answer before but missed how important the event action and label were. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is collisions in the `CONCAT()`.  You can try using a separator:

```
 count(distinct CONCAT(fullVisitorId, ':', CAST(visitId AS STRING))) as unique_events
```

This is just a possibility.

Another possibility is that one or the other value is `NULL`.  `COALESCE()` can help:

```
 count(distinct CONCAT(COALESCE(fullVisitorId, ''), ':', COALESCE(CAST(visitId AS STRING), ''))) as unique_events
```

Comment: The results remain the same even with the separator unfortunately.